# Reading something from a file and putting it under a data type

Tags: parsing, haskell, file-io, io

I have a file that contains this:

```
(Float,Float,Float)"sometext"
(Float,Float,Float)"sometext"
(Float,Float,Float)"sometext"
...
...
```

and I would like my program to read a line from the file, put the (Float,Float,Float) into a tripple and "sometext" into a String and all of it under a new data type so the whole thing would look like this:

SomeDataType (Float,Float,Float) "sometext"

I got this so far:

```
readFromDisc filePath = do 
                        fileHandle <- openFile "/tmp/lala.txt" ReadMode
                        contents <- hGetContents fileHandle
                        putStrLn $ readOneLine contents
```

If the file contains this:

```
(5.0,6.0,7.0)"faraway"
(8.0,9.0,0.0)"holdon"
```

I get:

```
"(5.0,6.0,7.0)\"faraway\""
```

Now, since I get that as a String I was thinking of using

```
breakInput input = break (=='"') input
```

To get this:

```
("(5.0,6.0,7.0)","\"faraway\"")
```

Which is a pair of strings, and I was going to use something to parse the tripple and the text out of it, but all of it doesn't feel right.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `reads` function.  It will parse the matching part at the beginning of the string, and return the rest of the string.

```
parseLine :: String -> [((Double, Double, Double), String)]
parseLine line = do
  (tuple, line') <- reads line
  (string, _)    <- reads line'
  return (tuple, string)

-- parseLine "(5.0, 6.0, 7.0)\"faraway\"" ---> ((5.0, 6.0, 7.0), "faraway")
```

This will return a list of matches, and ignore junk at the end of the line.  Since your particular case has an unambiguous parse, only one match will be produced by a successful parse.

Comment: +1. But use `Double` instead of `Int`. Also to make the solution complete: using `lines` to split into lines is easier. Everything as a one-liner: `return . map parseLine . lines =<< readFile "r.txt"`.

Comment: @jetxee Thanks for completing the solution.  I fixed the type signature.

Comment: YOu should also seriously consider Parsec, if it's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
readThat (triple, str) = SomeDataType (read triple :: (Float, Float, Float)) 
                                      (read str :: String)
```

Quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack, if you don't care about handling errors:

```
data SomeDataType = SomeDataType (Float, Float, Float) String
                  deriving Read

readOneLine s = read ("SomeDataType " ++ s)
```